# A very complicated SQL query that probably involves some JOINs and updating, deleting certain columns in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am not sure if this can be accomplished in one query but since I am new to SQL I might not know what SQL is capable of..

Say I have a table T, that looks like this -

```
id | some_other_fields | managed_by_sarah
1  | some_other_values | 1
2  | some_other_values | 1
3 | some_other_values | 0
```

So some rows will have `managed_by_sarah=1` and some will have it `=0`, it is treated as a boolean value.

Then I have some other values pulled from backedend. I have already formatted into values so now it is a list of values (let's call it list `L`) that can be inserted into `table T`. Every record in the list has `managed_by_sarah=1`.

I want to update all the records in `table T` that has `managed_by_sarah=1`. Four scenarios below -

- If a record has `managed_by_sarah=1` in `table T` and another record with the same id appears in `list L`, then update the original record in `table T` to have all the new field values from `list L`.
- If a record has `managed_by_sarah=1` in `table T` but no matching record in `list L` with the same id, then delete this record
- If a record in `list L` does not show up `table T` then add it to `table T`.
- If a record has `managed_by_sarah=0`, don't do anything regardless.

I was only able to write a query to cover the 1st scenario, 3rd and 4th one. Can all four scenarios be accomplished in one query?

Here is my query so far -

`INSERT INTO T (id, name, ... managed_by_sarah)
    VALUES (())
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    id=VALUES(id),
    name=VALUES(name),
    ...
    managed_by_sarah=VALUES(managed_by_sarah);`

Comment: You might need to use a transaction here if you want all four updates/deletes/inserts to happen atomically.  Are you open to using a transaction?

Comment: I think so.. I don't know much about transactions actually since I just started learning SQL. as far as i understand it's just a sequence of queries right?

Comment: If I use transaction, I should just add a second query that handles scenario 2 and that should do the job right?

Comment: You can think of a transaction as a way of ensuring that either your entire 4 steps complete or none of them do.  This doesn't answer your question but rather suggests _how_ you might go about doing it.

Comment: Consider whether you really need to DELETE data, as opposed to having a 'deleted' column that records a Boolean value against each row.